# Error al instalar Dlib. InvokeAi

Tags: python, cmake

soy nuevo en esto y quizás no de la información de la manera adecuada pero lo intentare.

Mi objetivo principal es poder acceder al scrip de configuracion de InvokeAi para eliminar un modelo que me daño el programa. Pero al buscar entrar usando PowerShell me dice que me hace falta tener Dlib instalado, ya instale CMake 3.26.3, Python 3.11.3, Visual Studio 1.77.3, Visual C++ Redistributable, las extensiones de CMake Tools y C++ en Visual estudio, literalmente todo lo que me ha ido pidiendo y me sigue dando el siguiente error:

```
PS C:\Users\xxx\Downloads\dlib-19.24\dlib-19.24> pip install dlib
Collecting dlib
  Using cached dlib-19.24.1.tar.gz (3.2 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Building wheels for collected packages: dlib
  Building wheel for dlib (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Building wheel for dlib (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [82 lines of output]
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      running build_ext
      <string>:129: DeprecationWarning: distutils Version classes are deprecated. Use packaging.version instead.
      Building extension for Python 3.11.3 (tags/v3.11.3:f3909b8, Apr  4 2023, 23:49:59) [MSC v.1934 64 bit (AMD64)]
      Invoking CMake setup: 'cmake C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-2pzjq3ed\dlib_0d5ff504a7ba4860ae3526cb77134bde\tools\python -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-2pzjq3ed\dlib_0d5ff504a7ba4860ae3526cb77134bde\build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311 -DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\python.exe -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_RELEASE=C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-2pzjq3ed\dlib_0d5ff504a7ba4860ae3526cb77134bde\build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311 -A x64'
      -- Building for: NMake Makefiles
      CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:5 (message):



    !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!


    You must use Visual Studio to build a python extension on windows.  If you
    are getting this error it means you have not installed Visual C++.  Note
    that there are many flavors of Visual Studio, like Visual Studio for C#
    development.  You need to install Visual Studio for C++.


    !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
```

Nota: como pueden ver tambien intente descargar una version precompilada de Dlib y ejecutarla con "python setup.py install" desde su ruta, pero me da exactamente el mismo error.

De antemano, muchas gracias!